# Why does this closure code throw an error when not using a capture list?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func biggerOne(_ a : Int, _ b : Int) -> Int? {
    if a == b {
        return nil
    } else if a > b {
        return a
    } else {
        return b
    }
}

var someClosure : (Int, Int) -> Int? = biggerOne(_:_:)

// Not working
someClosure = { (left : Int, right : Int) in
    someClosure(left , right)
}
print(someClosure(2,3)!)

// Working
someClosure = { [someClosure] (left : Int, right : Int) in
    someClosure(left , right)
}
print(someClosure(2,3)!)
```

I knew that closure uses capture list to store values ​​on creation so can solve the problem but why is the code above not working?

If you have any ideas, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why would you ever say either of those  in the first place? Does this code have any goal at all?

Comment: @matt Just for study. There's no special goal..

Comment: So you're deliberately forming an infinite loop and then asking why it's infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without capturing, `someClosure` here is simply calling itself, and then causing a stack overflow:

```
someClosure = { (left : Int, right : Int) in
   someClosure(left , right) // this call refers to the new value of "someClosure"
}
```

(I'm not sure if the fact that this passes compilation is intentional.)

This is just like as if you have defined a named function like:

```
func someClosure(left: Int, right: Int): Int? {
    someClosure(left: left, right: right)
}
```

On the other hand, the capture list captures the old value of `someClosure`, so "`someClosure`" inside the closure body refers to the captured value (i.e. the old value), and there is no infinite recursion. You can think of this as:

```
let captured = someClosure
someClosure = { (left : Int, right : Int) in
    captured(left , right)
}
```

Using `lldb yourExecutable` and the `thread backtrace` command, you can see the many duplicated stack frames that are caused by the recursion.

```
(lldb) thread backtrace 
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7bf6ffff8)
  * frame #0: 0x00007ff822e4fa99 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_beginAccess + 41
    frame #1: 0x0000000100003d87 yourExecutable`$s14yourExecutableSiSgSi_SitcfU_ + 71
    frame #2: 0x0000000100003dbc yourExecutable`$s14yourExecutableSiSgSi_SitcfU_ + 124
    frame #3: 0x0000000100003dbc yourExecutable`$s14yourExecutableSiSgSi_SitcfU_ + 124
    frame #4: 0x0000000100003dbc yourExecutable`$s14yourExecutableSiSgSi_SitcfU_ + 124
    ...
    frame #65515: 0x0000000100003dbc yourExecutable`$s14yourExecutableSiSgSi_SitcfU_ + 124
    frame #65516: 0x0000000100003dbc yourExecutable`$s14yourExecutableSiSgSi_SitcfU_ + 124
    frame #65517: 0x0000000100003baa yourExecutable`main + 218
    frame #65518: 0x00000001000154fe dyld`start + 462
```

Answer (score 1):

There are circular references, `someClosure` is calling itself.

Try eliminating the circular references:

```
        // Now it works
        let firstClosure = { (left : Int, right : Int) in
            someClosure(left , right)
        }
        print(firstClosure(2,3)!)
        
        // Working
        let secondClosure = { [someClosure] (left : Int, right : Int) in
            someClosure(left , right)
        }
        print(secondClosure(2,3)!)
```